# How to delete the entire Exchange Calender activities using Java EWS api?

Tags: java, web-services, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I have written the code as below where it deletes the Appointment having current  date but is there a way where i can delete the entire Calendar Appointments in one shot. Thanks in Advance

```
epublic static HashSet<String> userEventEws(ExchangeService service)  {

    HashSet<String> listSubject = new HashSet<String>();

        Calendar yesterday = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

        yesterday.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
        now.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        Date startDate = yesterday.getTime();
        Date endDate = now.getTime();

        try {
            CalendarFolder calendarFolder = CalendarFolder.bind(service, WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, new PropertySet());
            CalendarView cView = new CalendarView(startDate,endDate);
            cView.setPropertySet(new PropertySet(AppointmentSchema.Subject, AppointmentSchema.Start, AppointmentSchema.End));// we can set other properties 
            // as well depending upon our need.
            FindItemsResults appointments = calendarFolder.findAppointments(cView);

            List <Appointment>appList = appointments.getItems();
            for (Appointment appointment : appList) {
                listSubject.add(appointment.getSubject().trim());
                appointment.delete(DeleteMode.HardDelete);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    return listSubject;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally the two options you have is you can batch delete the Items that you return from FindItems (find appointments will expand the recurring appointments which if you want to delete all the Items you don't want to do just delete the Master and single instances instead see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn626016(v=exchg.150).aspx#bk_deleteews )

The other option would be to use the Empty Folder operation which should work in 2013 and above https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff709484%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx